# Try to redirect depending on subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have two folders:

- In the folder A is the site that hosted the page with the domain `www.mydomain`.
- And `mydomain.com` and in the folder B is the site with the domain `demo.mydomain.com`

How can I do that? I try the following but it does not work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}




 server {
            listen  80;
            server_name www.example.com example.com;
            root /var/www/html/folderA;
    }



 server {
            listen 80;
            server_name   ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;

            # Sets the correct root
            root /var/www/html/folderB;

    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, use mix `example.com` and `example.net` - are these supposed to be the same or different domains?

Comment: sorry typing mistake, i already have corrected

Comment: Change the first `server_name www.example.com example.com;` to `server_name www.example.com;` and change the second one from `server_name   ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;` to `server_name demo.example.com;`.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for your help finally I could resolve this issue

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/folderA;
    index index.php index.html;


    rewrite ^/folderB/(.*)$ http://demo.example.com/$1? permanent;

     location /images {
               autoindex on;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  demo.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/folderB;
    index index.php index.html;

     location /images {
               autoindex on;
        }
}
```